# Mistakenly turned a file to binary

Tags: grep

I was searching for the lines starting with `total value (->)`, and wrote `grep -> out.results`.

Now my file is binary. How can I turn it to human readable ?

`file out.results` says 'data', and when I try to open it, asks `It's a binary, do you still want to see it?`

Comment: `hexdump -C out.results | less` may give you a better idea of what is in your file now

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but you haven't “turned a file to binary”, you've erased its contents. `> out.results` truncates the file `out.results` and writes new content to it. Whatever the current contents are, they are not the result of transforming the old content, they're whatever grep wrote there.

You'll have to reconstruct the file or recover it from a backup. (You can *try* recovering the file from the free space on the disk, but that rarely works: you need to be lucky enough that it hasn't been overwritten yet and you need to find all the bits —  the blocks of a file are not stored consecutively on a disk in general.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you delete the file.

```
 grep -> u
```

split into

- `grep` grep with no pattern on ...
- `-` standart input ...
- `>` redirected ...
- `u` to file u.

Edit thanks to @Fiximan:

this will <s>fill file (`u`) with wahtever you typed on command line.</s>  create an empty file since there is no pattern to be `grep`ped and thus the output is no match for all entries.

Comment: Actually it will create an empty file since there is no pattern to be `grep`ped and thus the output is no match for all entries. This might be good if OP wants to recover the file since the data possibly have not been overwritten yet.

Comment: I'm afraid my output file turned into a binary.

Comment: @Archemar `file out.results` says `data`, and when I try to open it, warns `It's a binary, do you still want to see it?`.